# Using XML files to store data in C#

Tags: c#, xml, database, file-io

I'm basically looking for someone to point me in the right direction on this. I read through some of the Microsoft documentation, but that wasn't very helpful. This is my first attempt at working with XML.

I'm writing an application that needs to store a list of known users and a list of aliases created by each of those users. I've figured out how to have my lists serialized and stored to XML files when the application closes and have it retrieve those when the application opens again, but I don't want to keep the list of users and aliases in memory.

In order for this to work, I need to have the ability to search, edit, and append to the XML file during run time.

The XML structure I envision is something like:

```
<UserRecord>
    <User>Username-1</User>
    <AliasRecord>
        <Alias>Alias-1</Alias>
        <Number>6135551234</Number>
    </AliasRecord>
    <AliasRecord>
        <Alias>Alias-2</Alias>
        <Number>6131238888</Number>
    </AliasRecord>
</UserRecord>
```

Each user would only have one username but could have multiple aliases. I need to have the ability to add users, add aliases to a new or existing user, and change existing aliases. Usernames would never change, but an entire User record could be deleted.

So far, the only XML I've done in C# uses serialization but I don't think that approach will work for the above.

```
    private void WriteXML()
    {
        try
        {
            System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer XMLwriter = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(MessageRecord));

            System.IO.StreamWriter XMLfile = new System.IO.StreamWriter("Saved MessageRecords.xml");
            foreach (MessageRecord mr in OutgoingMessages)
            {
                XMLwriter.Serialize(XMLfile, mr);
            }
            XMLfile.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why not use a database instead?

Comment: @reggaeguitar I don't want to use a database, as I'm going to be porting this to other platforms at some point, and the data shown above is the limit of what I have to store.

Comment: As was suggested, I decided to search for Linq to XML tutorials and found one that gave me exactly what I needed, so I thought I'd share it here. http://www.dotnetcurry.com/showarticle.aspx?ID=564 Thank you to all those who responded.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Create two classes to represent `UserRecord` and `AliasRecord`.

```
public class UserRecord
{
    public string User { get; set; }
    public List<AliasRecord> AliasRecords { get; set; }
}

public class AliasRecord
{
    public string Alias { get; set; }
    public string Number { get; set; }
}
```

Populate them like this:

```
 var userRecord = new UserRecord 
 { 
     User = "UserName1", 
     AliasRecord = new List<AliasRecord> {
        new AliasRecord { Alias = "Alias1", Number = "12345678" }, 
        new AliasRecord { Alias = "Alias2", Number = "23456789" }
     }
 };
```

And use this code to serialize/deserialize it:

```
public static class XmlHelper
{
    public static bool NewLineOnAttributes { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Serializes an object to an XML string, using the specified namespaces.
    /// </summary>
    public static string ToXml(object obj, XmlSerializerNamespaces ns)
    {
        Type T = obj.GetType();

        var xs = new XmlSerializer(T);
        var ws = new XmlWriterSettings { Indent = true, NewLineOnAttributes = NewLineOnAttributes, OmitXmlDeclaration = true };

        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(sb, ws))
        {
            xs.Serialize(writer, obj, ns);
        }
        return sb.ToString();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Serializes an object to an XML string.
    /// </summary>
    public static string ToXml(object obj)
    {
        var ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
        ns.Add("", "");
        return ToXml(obj, ns);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Deserializes an object from an XML string.
    /// </summary>
    public static T FromXml<T>(string xml)
    {
        XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
        using (StringReader sr = new StringReader(xml))
        {
            return (T)xs.Deserialize(sr);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Deserializes an object from an XML string, using the specified type name.
    /// </summary>
    public static object FromXml(string xml, string typeName)
    {
        Type T = Type.GetType(typeName);
        XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(T);
        using (StringReader sr = new StringReader(xml))
        {
            return xs.Deserialize(sr);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Serializes an object to an XML file.
    /// </summary>
    public static void ToXmlFile(object obj, string filePath)
    {
        var xs = new XmlSerializer(obj.GetType());
        var ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
        var ws = new XmlWriterSettings { Indent = true, NewLineOnAttributes = NewLineOnAttributes, OmitXmlDeclaration = true };
        ns.Add("", "");

        using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(filePath, ws))
        {
            xs.Serialize(writer, obj, ns);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Deserializes an object from an XML file.
    /// </summary>
    public static T FromXmlFile<T>(string filePath)
    {
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(filePath);
        try
        {
            var result = FromXml<T>(sr.ReadToEnd());
            return result;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw new Exception("There was an error attempting to read the file " + filePath + "\n\n" + e.InnerException.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            sr.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Example usage:

```
var result = XmlHelper.ToXml(userRecord);
```

Result:

```
<UserRecord>
    <User>Username1</User>
    <AliasRecords>
        <AliasRecord>
            <Alias>Alias1</Alias>
            <Number>12345678</Number>
        </AliasRecord>
        <AliasRecord>
            <Alias>Alias2</Alias>
            <Number>23456789</Number>
        </AliasRecord>
    </AliasRecords>
</UserRecord>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed! Thank you. I just needed a place to start. I'll study what you provided and use it as a starting point.

Comment: "I am a strong believer in code clarity and simplicity."... it shows.