# C# Loading in Data with XML File

Tags: c#, xml, adventure

I have an end of the semester project where I have to create a text based adventure which seem to be a very popular thing to get understand object-oriented code. I'm using an XML file to populate the Rooms. My Room class has a constructor that looks like this:

```
Room(int ID, string Name, string SDescription, string LDescription, int RoomToN, ...)
{
     ID = id;
     Name = name;
     ...
}
```

Normally, to create an object room, you would write:

```
 Room room = new Room();
 Room.ID = 1;
```

and so on. With the XML file how will I accomplish that? I'm a little confused.

Comment: Try the code that I've posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25369059.  It will work for almost any arbitrary C# object.  Build up a C# object containing the data you need (as I've shown in the example), and then use the helper methods to save or load the XML into the C# object.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Wow! That is awesome. Thank you so much!